# Splitting a string across multiple lines in class file

Tags: c#

Lets say I have a really long string that I need to have across multiple lines in the text editor for readability. Should I use StringBuffer or does it not matter? In other words is this:

```
string my_string = "there are lots of " +
"words here";
```

The same as this as far as performance goes?

```
string my_string = "there are lots of words here";
```

In other words, will I be creating multiple string objects in the first example and only one in the second? I want to make sure performance doesn`t suffer for readability purposes.

Comment: Your first code snippet will create a single string, it is just a call to `string.Concat`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Apparently my search-fu needs work as I couldn`t find the answer before